# Restoring Deleted Azure SQL Database From Portal - Failing Deployment With InternalServerError

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am attempting to test some disaster recovery procedures in Azure.

I have taken a copy of a production Azure SQL database on a test server, deleted it, and am attempting to restore it using the "Deleted databases" option under the SQL Server. When restoring the deleted database backup, it fails after ~34 minutes with:

> Status: Failed
>
> Code: InternalServerError
>
> Message: An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'xxxxxxxxxx'

Screenshot:

[image]

I have tried twice now without success. This is concerning since I am not sure this same issue would occur when trying to restore the production database in the same scenario.

What could be causing this problem? I did the same test using the Sample AdventureWorksLT source and it worked just fine, so it seems to be something with my application's production database specifically.

Comment: Have you tested exporting to bacpac that Production database and then import the bacpac from storage account? I would love to see if the import fails the same as the restore. If the import fails you may get a more detailed error.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo I have not tried this route yet since it's not really the recovery case I am trying to test. Maybe I can try that though if it would give more information.

Comment: That's my interest to test that route.

Comment: Same issue here. Any one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PowerShell instead of the portal.  Also, the "Conflict" status suggests you are restoring an object with the same name as the running DB, try giving adding *_restored* to the name of the restored DB.

```
PS C:\>$DeletedDatabase = Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01"
PS C:\> Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromDeletedDatabaseBackup -DeletionDate $DeletedDatabase.DeletionDate -ResourceGroupName $DeletedDatabase.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $DeletedDatabase.ServerName -TargetDatabaseName "RestoredDatabase" -ResourceId $DeletedDatabase.ResourceID -Edition "Standard" -ServiceObjectiveName "S2" -PointInTime UTCDateTime
```

The first command gets the deleted database backup that you want to restore by using `Get-AzSqlDeletedDatabaseBackup`. The second command starts the restore from the deleted database backup by using the `Restore-AzSqlDatabase` cmdlet. If the `-PointInTime` parameter is not specified, the database will be restored to the deletion time.

Comment: There are no other databases on this test server so I am not sure why there would be a conflict. The restored name has the date already appended onto it as well, which would make it unique. I will see if I can get something to work from the powershell route.

Comment: I tried using PowerShell and also received an error. `Restore-AzSqlDatabase : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx''
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromDeletedDatabaseBackup -DeletionDate $Delet ...
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Restore-AzSqlDatabase], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Backup.Cmdlet.RestoreAzureRmSqlDatabase`